# Separar el codigo de los botones en PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Quiero escribir el codigo que llame a un boton en PyQt5, separado del archivo principal (el archivo con el codigo del boton, se llama **Botones**), algo asi como esto:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
def Boton1(nombre, funcion):
    Boton = QPushButton(nombre)
    Boton.clicked.connect(funcion)
```

Sin embargo al llamarlo desde el archivo principal, algo asi como esto:

```
import Botones

Botones.Boton1("Nuevo boton", prueba)

def prueba(self):
    print("funciona.")
```

no logro hacer que funcione.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro pero pueden ser dos causas distintas.

1. La funcion prueba se definio despues de ser asignada al boton, por
   lo que se asigno nada al boton
2. la funcion prueba no existe para el archivo Botones por lo que
   Boton1 quedo sin funcion.

Ambas son a causa de que la funcion no existe

Solucion: anteponer la definicion de la funcion a su uso

```
import Botones

def prueba(self):
    print("funciona.")

Botones.Boton1("Nuevo boton", prueba)
```

El codigo que subiste esta incompleto, la proxima subelo entero.